# How to pass a struct member as an argument in fopen()?

Tags: segmentation-fault

I'm new in C. I read a file and then from that file, I get name of another file which I need to read again. I store the name of the file in a struct, but when I pass the filename from the struct it shows error. The program compiles with no error, but shows segmentation fault: 11

```
struct InfoConf {
char log[20], file_path[20], log_path[30], ver[10];
};
int main(){

struct InfoConf configfile;
char *str9 = "File Path";
char line[255];
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("config_1.conf","r");

while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != NULL){
    char* val1 = strtok(line, ":");
    char* val2 = strtok(NULL, ":");
    if(strcmp(str9, val1) == 0){
        strcpy(configfile.file_path, val2);
    }
}

FILE *fp1;
fp1 = fopen(configfile.file_path, "r");

if(fp1 == NULL){
    perror("Error in opening Meta-data file: "); //Error in opening Meta-data file: : No such file or directory
}

}
```

Comment: The first assignment `configfile.file_path = "testFile.mdf"` won't compile, both for syntax and semantic error.

Comment: I actually used the strcpy(), please look at the updated version. Same error.

Comment: Still does not compile. And uncompilable code certainly won't work. Please show the _actual_ piece of code.

Comment: Maybe the problem is in your data file, instead of in passing a parameter to a function. Does the file exist at all? Does your program have appropriate access rights to read it?  Would it work if you replace the call with explicit `fopen("testFile.mdf", "r")` ...?

Comment: yes the file exist, when I write fopen("filename", "r") it works perfectly.

Comment: please see the updated code above

Comment: What is a format of the line you are splitting with `strtok()`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you cannot copy string directly using "=".
the right code is:

```
/* attention: "=" is used for string definition and assignment together */
char name[] = "testFile.mdf"; 

/* attention: strlen(name) < sizeof(configfile.file_path)
 *            strcpy function is used for string assignment after definition.
 **/
strcpy(configfile.file_path, name);
/* add printf for debug */
printf("configfile.file_path:%s\n",configfile.file_path);
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly your 'path' contains a whitespace character at the end.
This is a common problem when a U*x application reads text files prepared in Windows: the DOS-like line endings consist of a char pair CR,LF (`^M^J`, ASCII codes 13,10) and Unix/Linux application expects just a LineFeed (`^J`, code 10) – as a result the 'superfluous' CR gets appended to the 'contents' of the line, and you app may be trying to open `testFile.mdf^M` file instead of `testFile.mdf`.

Comment: @IOstream Test if this _is_ the issue first. What is your OS? What's the source of your config file? Does it actually have CR+LF line endings? And if so, is your application prepared to recognize them properly?

Answer (score 0):

Always add checks to make sure that any pointer you pass to `strcpy` and `strcmp` are valid pointers.

Change the `while` loop to:

```
while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != NULL)
{
   // Copy the line first before tokenizing so you have the original line
   // for messages.
   char line_copy[255];
   strcpy(line_copy, line);

   char* val1 = strtok(line, ":");
   char* val2 = strtok(NULL, ":");
   if ( val1 != NULL )
   {
      if(strcmp(str9, val1) == 0)
      {
         if ( val2 != NULL )
         {
            strcpy(configfile.file_path, val2);
         }
         else
         {
            // Print diagnostic message.
            printf("Unable to tokenize line: %s\n", line_copy);
         }
      }
   }
   else
   {
      // Print diagnostic message.
      printf("Unable to tokenize line: %s\n", line_copy);
   }
}
```